# How can I configure dnsmasq as a simple subdomain authoritative server (re: home network)

Tags: dns, dnsmasq

I'm trying to use dnsmasq as the primary dns server for my private network and I'd like dnsmasq to return authoritative responses for *.home.mydomain.com but also recursively resolve all other queries.

For example, dnsmasq is running on my Linux (Debian) server at 192.168.1.50.

I'd like to point my clients to this server and if 'service.home.mydomain.com' is queried then I'd like an authoritative response.  However, if 'www.google.com' is queried then it should forward it to a public server and then return the response.

Is this possible?  Can somebody provide a sample setup?

Here is my dnsmasq.conf but if I query anything besides home.mydomain.com it returns REFUSED:

```
log-queries

no-resolv

server=8.8.4.4
server=8.8.8.8

auth-server=server.home.mydomain.com,enp2s0f0
auth-zone=home.mydomain.com,192.168.1.0/24
host-record=server.home.mydomain.com,192.168.1.50
```

Comment: Does the default Dnsmasq behavior not work for you?

Comment: No, I'm trying to use a wildcard CNAME (not wildcard A record) which requires an authoritative DNS setup.